# Is there a way to "reliableWrite" descriptors in BLE (Android)? I'm trying to write them too fast and they're failing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to setup a BLE communication with a device.  I have multiple characteristics that are able to be setup for notifications.  I do so, using setCharacteristicNotifications as well as writing the CCCD descriptor.  However, when I try to write multiple descriptors in a row, they seem to lap each other, which leads to errors.  For example, this is my code looping through the found characteristics that allow notifications:

```
for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
    if (ArrayUtils.contains(acceptable_characteristics, characteristic.getUuid())) {
        Log.i("Characteristic found", characteristic.getUuid().toString());
        Descr= characteristic.getDescriptors();
        for (BluetoothGattDescriptor d: Descr){
            if (ArrayUtils.contains(cccd, d.getUuid())) {
                Log.i("CCCD", d.getUuid().toString());
                boolean set = d.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                String result = String.valueOf(set);
                Log.i("DidItSet", result);
                boolean write = mGatt.writeDescriptor(d);
                String resultW = String.valueOf(write);
                Log.i("DidItWrite", resultW);
                }
            }

        mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

    }
}
```

My onDescriptorWrite looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDescriptorWrite (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
    String value = new String(descriptor.getValue());
    String permission = new String(descriptor.getValue());
    Log.i("onDescriptorWriteV", value);
    Log.i("onDescriptorWriteP", permission);
    Log.i("onDescriptorWriteS", Integer.toString(status));
    }
```

You can see the problem in the log:

```
08-12 22:53:17.227 I/Characteristic found: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-12 22:53:17.228 I/CCCD: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-12 22:53:17.228 I/DidItSet: true
08-12 22:53:17.251 I/DidItWrite: true
08-12 22:53:17.251 D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
08-12 22:53:17.252 I/Characteristic found: 00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-12 22:53:17.252 I/CCCD: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-12 22:53:17.252 I/DidItSet: true
08-12 22:53:17.252 I/DidItWrite: false
08-12 22:53:17.252 D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
08-12 22:53:17.256 I/Characteristic found: 00002a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-12 22:53:17.747 I/onDescriptorWriteV: ��
08-12 22:53:17.747 I/onDescriptorWriteP: ��
08-12 22:53:17.747 I/onDescriptorWriteS: 0
```

The first descriptor is found and is written fine.  The second descriptor is found but the write fails.  Then the callback for the first descriptor goes through (the values are garbage, but I don't care about that).  It takes a millisecond to move on to the next descriptor, but it takes about 500 ms to actually do the descriptor write, and it seems that before the write is finished, any subsequent writes will fail.  I then get the values of the one that was successfully written onCharacteristicChanged.

Now it seems like the BluetoothGatt class has methods called beginReliableWrite() and executeReliableWrite() in which writes are queued up and executed sequentially to prevent this sort of thing.  But the documentation makes it seem like it's only applicable for characteristic writes.  Does anyone know if there's a way of doing this with descriptor writes?  Or is there another way of making the descriptor writes wait for the previous one to finish?

Comment: Perhaps you could implement your own sort of queue: add descriptors to a list, and then have a separate thread execute them one at a time, each time waiting for the callback to finish before writing the next

Comment: ^^ This. I do this in my app. Works great.